# find all the sets of 4 no.s from given vector such that their sum is equal to target and there should not be any duplicate sets.(leetcode)(O(n^3))

Tags: c++, c++14

i am using this two pointers approach but  it is not passing all the test cases. It is not able to find all such sets, i just want to know that why it is not finding all the sets. What is the problem in this code?

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> fourSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int n=nums.size();
        ///cout<<n<<endl;
        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
        vector<int>::iterator i1;
        vector<int>::iterator j1;
        vector<vector<int>> v;
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n-3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<n-2;j++)
            {
                i1=nums.begin()+j+1;
                j1=nums.end()-1;
                while(i1<j1)
                {
                    sum=nums[i]+nums[j]+*i1+*j1;
                    if(sum==target)
                    {
                        vector<int> v2;
                        v2.push_back(nums[i]);
                        v2.push_back(nums[j]);
                        v2.push_back(*i1);
                        v2.push_back(*j1);
                        v.push_back(v2);//*/
                        i1++;
                        j1--;
                    }
                    else if(sum>target) j1--;
                    else i1++;
                }//*/
            }
        }/// to find store the sets.
        int s=v.size();
        for(int i=0;i<s-1;i++)
        {
            if(v[i]==v[i+1])
            {
                vector<vector<int>>::iterator p=v.begin()+i;
                v.erase(p);
            }
        }///to remove duplicates.
        return v;
    }
};
```

It is a LEETCODE problem and its title is 4sum.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: Please add the problem description directly in to the question.

Comment: Isn't this kind of question more suitable to ask on the LeetCode forums?

Comment: Last loop seems to be simplifiable with `std::unique`, but that seems wrong anyway, for `{0 0 0 1 2 2 3}, 4`, you would have `[{0 0 1 3}, {0 0 2 2}, {0 0 1 3}, {0 0 2 2}]`.